# What does "Can not connect to the database in its current state" mean on azure-sql?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have recently started receiving "Can not connect to the database in its current state." when trying to connect to my Azure SQL database.  As far as I am aware nothing has changed and I get the same error using the query tool in the Azure portal itself using etiher sql authentication or Azure Ad authentication.

The server status is "online" and the trouble-shooter says that it can not find any issues. I have a limit on the billing of the account but have not hit it.

I cant find any way of "restarting" the sql instance or any logs that indicate what might be wrong.  I cant raise a support ticket as the troubleshooter suggests that nothing is wrong.

Does anyone have any insight as to what might cause this or what I might try to get it resovled?

Edit:  I believe that this is an error code for a Billing issue now - despite the billing appearing fine the subscription is disabled.  All of the help articles indicated that code changes were needed to connect reliably but I dont think that is the case.

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using SQL Database in the serverless mode?

Comment: Yes - General Purpose: Serverless, Gen5

Comment: my guess is that  it was a cold start problem, but can't be 100%

Comment: Its been out for over 24 hours now - I get the usual "startup" disconnect but that only lasts 30 seconds or so then it is up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Key Vault with Azure SQL Database? Make sure permissions to the key vault are properly set.

Another possible reason is the database may be in recovery state. In that case you may have to create a support ticket [here](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/managesupportrequest).

Comment: Hi - I'm not using Key vault, and its not actually possible to raise a support ticket there without paying for a support account ( hence the question here ) as it turns out this is a billing issue - the subscription is "disabled" which is what has caused the issue and you can raise a support incident for billing issues which is what I am doing.  Thank you for your help.